# Apply fixed-point iteration method for $f(x)=e^{x\sqrt{2x-1}}$. Is it possible?

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

I got this question as an exercise by my teacher (I think it can't be solved).

I know that the function $f(x)=e^{x\sqrt{2x-1}}$ doesn't have roots. How can you approximate a root that doesn't exist?

How can I show that the root **can't** be approximated by this method (or any other for that matter)?

Comment: It’s enough to show that $f(1/2)=1$ and that $f$ is increasing in the domain.

Comment: @Paul I see, that means it has no roots. So the conclusion would be: we can't use the method because the function has no roots. Right?

Comment: Not just no roots, but does not have 0 as a limit either.  You need to approach the value for fixed point iteration to work.

Comment: Understood, thank you.